# Calculating slope and intercept error of linear regression

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-regression

I have a very simple case of 3 Datapoints and I would like to do a linear fit `y=a0 + a1x` through those points using `np.polyfit` or `scipy.stats.linregress`.

For the further error propagation I need the errors in the slope and the intercept. I am by far no expert in statistics but on the scipy side I am only aware of the stderr which does not split in slope and intercept.
Polyfit has the possibly to estimate the covariance matrix, but this does not work with only 3 datapoints.

When using qtiplot for example it yields errors for slope and intercept.

```
B (y-intercept) = 9,291335740072202e-12 +/- 2,391260092282606e-13
A (slope) = 2,527075812274368e-12 +/- 6,878180102259077e-13
```

What would be the appropiate way to calculate these in python?

EDIT:

```
np.polyfit(x, y, 1, cov=True)
```

results in

> ValueError: the number of data points must exceed order + 2 for
>   Bayesian estimate the covariance matrix

Comment: How does the covariance matrix for polyfit "not work"? Please show us your example where it fails.

Comment: Why arent you using [scipy.stats.linregress](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) it gives slope, intercept, correleation coefficient, p value & standard error?

Answer (score 0):

[scipy.stats.linregress](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) gives you slope, intercept, correleation coefficient, p value & standard error. The fitted line does not have errors associated with its slope or intercept, the errors are to do with the distances of the points from the line. [Have a read through this to clear up the point](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/least-squares-regression-line/)

An example...

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = np.array([[1, 3], [2, 4], [2, 7]])
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(points)

print("slope = ", slope)
print("intercept = ", intercept)
print("R = ", r_value)
print("p = ", p_value)
print("Standard error = ", std_err)

for xy in points:
    plt.plot(xy[0], xy[1], 'ob')

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = slope * x + intercept
plt.plot(x, y, '-r')

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, but there are physical meaings to either slope and intercept. I have to calculate both seperatly and need to do an error propagation. Therefore it is necessary to get independent errors for both, slope and intercept. Is there a methode to do so?

Comment: sorry Fabian but I think you are misunderstanding the nature of the line of regression (Line of best fit). To have associated errors with the slope or intercept of the regressed line then the data points themselves must have associated errors, you make no mention of that in your question though. Otherwise there is only ONE line of best fit given a set of definite points with no associated errors.